# setcookie() issues on running with HTTPS on WordPress

Tags: php, headers

I have set 2 custom cookies to be saved when user clicks a button that runs the script to save the cookies.

The issue is that I need these to be saved through HTTPS because I am using them on a store locator page, and need a secured connection to allow for location detection to happen properly.

When I do not add TRUE for secure connection and leave code as shown below, the cookies save just fine when running through HTTP.

```
setcookie('lat', $_POST['lat'], time()+62208000, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
setcookie('lng', $_POST['lng'], time()+62208000, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

However, when I try to add TRUE for secure connection as shown below, it does not work properly with HTTPS running:

```
setcookie('lat', $_POST['lat'], time()+62208000, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], TRUE);
setcookie('lng', $_POST['lng'], time()+62208000, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], TRUE);
```

I have tried including httponly as either TRUE or FALSE as well, but nothing seems to have worked.

If anyone could give any tip about getting this resolved, I would appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both examples should work fine if your WordPress site is running on `https://`.

However, I would recommend you set up the cookies by using available constants and functions provided by WordPress, it makes things more organized. See example below:

```
setcookie( 'lat', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lat'] ), strtotime( '+14 days' ), '/', esc_COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );
```

Notice that I'm using `is_ssl` to check whether the site is running on **https** or not. This should work fine.

Also, don't insert any data coming from your web server environment without filtering it, always secure yourself.